# D - store reference to subarray in variable

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, reference, d, byref

I have code like this:

```
int[][] array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
auto line = array[0];
line ~= 5;
```

I assume `line` contains a copy of subarray and `array` is not modified when `line` is. Is it possible to store subarray as reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pointer to the first element of `array`:

```
int[][] array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
auto line = &array[0];
*line ~= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want can be handled with slices - https://dlang.org/d-array-article.html . If you want a copy, you use `.dup` (mutable), or `.idup` (immutable).